# Model Builder: How to iterate rasters into raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, iteration

[image: Model Builder]

[image: Map Algebra expression]

Above you can see I have a simple model in ArcGIS, when I run it, I change the ".tif" name in both sections of the calculation. I then hit OK, and it puts the new raster where it should be with all the various environmental variables. Save a lot of time, works great.

I want to take it a bit further, for example: repeat automatically for all .tifs in a specified directory.

How do I do this? I tried playing around with file / raster iterations but I was obviously doing something wrong because I just couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The model is simply this:

[image: Model]

The Raster calculator is set up as is:

[image: Raster calculator]

The expression is:

```
Con(IsNull("%myRaster%"),0,"%myRaster%")
```

The output raster is:

```
C:\Scratch\%Name%_V2.tif
```

The %Name% is the inline variable substitution using the Name output variable from the iterator.