# Using ModelBuilder with Raster Calculator and LCP Analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have 13 unique resistant surfaces, which will be used to run a least cost path analysis in ArcMap.

My problem lies in my understanding of ModelBuilder. I am hoping to set it up so for each path end (belonging to a specific population), ModelBuilder will start by multiplying the resistance layers for those two populations, and then go forward to run the least cost path analysis. However I have 13 populations and then multiple individuals (or path ends from each).

I am sure there is a way to do this using the iterators, but am unsure how I would set my equation up in rater calculator and then go on to connect my least cost path analysis.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404542/model-builder-how-to-iterate-rasters-into-raster-calculator

Comment: What does your model do far look like?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about R then please do that in a separate question and include a code attempt.